# Background process with limited resources

Tags: php, nginx, cron, apache2

I want to find an opportunity to limit the CPU usage CPU for script php. 
My script runs with the help of Cron tasks and works in the mode CLI.
The problem is that after starting the CPU usage is 100%.
What leads to the fact that the site on the same server stops responding to the execution time of the background task.
Is it possible to limit CPU usage for this script? For example, to 50% maximum.

VPS Linux Ubuntu 16.
RAM 6 GB.
CPU 2x.
PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `nice` or `renice` to low-priorize the process, e.g. `renice +10 1234` will make the process `1234` low priorized on scheduling (limits are `-20` to `+19` with smaller values renders to higher priority).

With `cpulimit` it is possible to limit the cpu usage, eg. `cpulimit -l 50 -p 1234` limits the process `1234` to `50%`.

see also https://scoutapm.com/blog/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Comment: Yes, it seems that I need. But everywhere you need to know UID process. It is possible to integrate it into a command of the type: "php console feed:generate" ?

Comment: It really works. I use "nice -n10 php console feed:generate"